# How to bind std::map to Lua with LuaBind

Tags: c++, lua

Is this possible in lua to achieve?

```
player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"] = "stand"
print (player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"])
```

I've done getter method in c++ with this approach:

```
luabind::object FakeScript::getProp()
{
    luabind::object obj = luabind::newtable(L);

    for(auto i = this->properties.begin(); i != this->properties.end(); i++)
    {
        obj[i->first] = i->second;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

But I'm stuck with setter. The first line in lua code which I'm trying to set value "stand" for key "stat" is not going to work and it keep redirecting me to the getter method. Setter method only works when I drop `["stat"]` from `properties`.

I can do something like this for setter in my script:

```
player.scripts["movement"].properties = {stat = "stand"}
```

But this isn't what I want because I have to go through my real keys in c++ to determine which key is placed in setter argument table value.

This is my map in class:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> properties;
```

Comment: Take a look at [Sol](https://github.com/Rapptz/sol)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to maintain the table entirely in C++.  You wouldn't have any actual properties in the Lua table at all; you'd just have a placeholder table with its `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods mapped to C++ functions that get and set properties from the underlying `std::map`.  I'm not familiar enough with LuaBind to show you the exact code to make this happen, but it shouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: Actually right now my table is entirely in C++. The getter method which is named as `getProp()` has been set as getter for the `properties` property of `FakeScript` class with LuaBind. This means `properties` is bind as a pointer in real Lua script which works with mine getter and setter. I've worked with metamethods, but it would ruin whole purpose of LuaBind if I do that and LuaBind itself is setting `__index` & `__newindex` fields. I can't do that.

Comment: But your `properties` getter is creating a Lua table that has the properties as actual entries in it, right?  That's what your `getProp()` function that you posted is doing, IIUC.  I'm saying it shouldn't put the actual properties in the Lua table at all - it should return a fake table, that has no actual entries, but just forwards to the `std::map` via metamethods (however that is done in LuaBind).

Comment: I got it. I should give this a try, but again it ruins the purpose of LuaBind. I can do this in plain Lua itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think Lua can access and create objects on tables with array-like syntax. If it doesnt, Squirrel (which is based on Lua, and have much more OOP sugars) can, here it is: http://squirrel-lang.org/doc/squirrel3.html

Your script would be looking like this:

```
player.scripts["movement"] <- new PlayerClass()
player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"] = "stand"
print (player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"])
```

Comment: I've tried squirrel language before and I say it's fantastic. Though I'm nearly finishing my engine and I can't change scripting language since I had to adapt my engine with it. I've done most of the things in squirrel that I wasn't able to do them in Lua. Although Lua is powerful, I wish I could get to know squirrel before using Lua.